# How to edit CSS class via jQuery if statement

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I have an if statement which checks the url for "ivnt", I would like the div "carriage-promo" to have height changed from it's dafault of 0px, to 40px.

I do not want to **add** a class or **remove** a class, I know how to achieve this already and it doesn't solve this problem I'm afraid.

Consider:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("invt") > -1) { 
    $('#promo-carriage').css{
          height: '40px'}
         }
      });
```

However, this is not working for me.  Any suggestions?  I'm quite sure this will be a syntax error, but I'm new to jQuery/JS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parenteses `.css()` and `height` inside a quote.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("invt") > -1) {
        $("#promo-carriage").css("height", "40px");
    }
});
```

Comment: Many thanks.  This worked very well, I am still having an issue but that's relating to a scrollTop(); animate...

I don't suppose you know how to make the height change and STAY changed haha?  I've tried return;  but that's not working!

Answer (score 2):

In summary, whenever you need to pass just one key + value pair, you can pass it as:

`$(element).css("attribute","value");`

while if you want to pass more than one declaration, use an object

`$(element).css({height:"200px", width:"100px", backgroundColor: "red"});` or
`$(element).css({height:"200px"});`

Note the differences between the two examples. In the object, you may or not, define the key inside the quotes, but preferably you should use the javascript definitions with no quotes and where "background-color" becomes backgroundColor:
The syntax also changes. Note that in the object, you separate the key and the value with double-colon : and the different pairs with comma.

For further reference, see http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Thanks for explaining, very clear. I haven't actually done this much but I'm finding it very useful!

Comment: @Myles at least you should upvote it.because other people can prefer to read it..

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opening parentheses after the css method:

```
$('#promo-carriage').css({
```

However, if you are trying to hide/show something, I recommend not using the height property to do it.  You want to use the CSS `display` property.

There are quick jQuery methods to change the display of an object:

```
$("#promo-carriage").toggle()
$("#promo-carriage").hide()
$("#promo-carriage").show()
```

Here is a quick and easy [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2E8nC/).

Comment: There's lots of other jQuery going on for showing/hiding/animating this particular element.  I don't want to complicate things further!

Thanks for your answer though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`''` missing for `height` I guess,And another possibility is use [height method](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2) directly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if(window.location.href.indexOf("invt") > -1) { 
    $('#promo-carriage').height('40px');
      });
```